# SFML library: http request

Tags: javascript, c++, post, httprequest, sfml

I want to send an HTTP Post Request to a server. First I followed an YT tutorial which explained everything very well. So out of this tutorial I created the following code:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        if(xhr.status == 200){
          document.getElementById('show_data').textContent = xhr.responseText;
        }
        if (xhr.status == 404){
          console.log("ERROR 404. File not found");
        }
      }
    };
 
 var mode = JSON.stringify({"mode":"JSON"});
 var enumerate = JSON.stringify({"device":[{"command":"enumerate"}]});

    xhr.open('post', 'http://192.168.2.100', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application//x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(enumerate);
```

But now the project requieres to be written in C++. After some research I found the SFML Library. I want to send the same Request as above. However the only response I get is "404". Can anybody help me with this issue?

C++ Code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string json_mode = "{\"mode\":\"JSON\"}";
    string enumerate = "{\"device\":[{\"command\":\"enumerate\"}]}";

    // +++DOESN'T WORK+++
    //Request:
    sf::Http http;
    http.setHost("http://192.168.2.100");
    sf::Http::Request request;
    request.setMethod(sf::Http::Request::Post);
    request.setUri("/index.html");
    request.setBody(enumerate);
    //Response:
    sf::Http::Response response = http.sendRequest(request);
    if (response.getStatus() == sf::Http::Response::Ok)
    {
    cout << response.getStatus() << endl;
    cout << response.getMajorHttpVersion() << endl;
    cout << response.getMinorHttpVersion() << endl;
    cout << response.getBody() <<endl;
    //Here I only get "404" as an answer.
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "error: " << response.getStatus() << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

I'm greatful with every piece of advice or tip. Or if you have ideas to make it easier/better let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, Probably the `index.html` does no exist in the root of the web server in the address `192.168.2.100`?

Comment: try `request.setUri("/");`

Comment: @inaliahgle thank you so much. Works perfectly fine. case closed

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is rather simple. The "host" for the server is only the server name, not the protocol. The field is used by the server to actually determine which host your tried to reach (since a single server could serve multiple sites with different domain names).

You can skip the call to `sf::Http::setHost()` completely by just using the constructor:

```
sf::Http http("192.168.2.100");
```

Or if you really want to call it, just do so:

```
http.setHost("192.168.2.100");
```

If this doesn't solve the problem, check your server's log files. There should be the requests, if they've reached it.

---

Just for reference, how an URL/URI is constructed:

```
http://192.168.2.100:8000/index.html
|-----| <- Protocol (you define this by specifically using sf::Http over sf::Ftp for example)

http://192.168.2.100:8000/index.html
       |-----------| <- Host

http://192.168.2.100:8000/index.html
                    |---| <- Port (optional)

http://192.168.2.100:8000/index.html
                          |--------| <- URI/document (optional and might serve a server dependent default, if empty)
```

Comment: Makes sense. However the problem was, as mentioned in the comment above, the URI. I had to set it to "/" in order to get the response I want. But still thank you, cause I didn't know how an URL was constructed.

Comment: @David9472 Ah, okay, That might be a configuration thing then. Most servers will server an `/index.html` as `/` as well, but it's also possible the actual file is called `/index.htm` or similar. This would be on a case by case basis.